# SQL: get average of last 2 purchases and indicate number of purchases found

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the last two purchases of each article (and average them out) and know how many purchases were found (some may have none, one or many)

I'm trying to do something like this

```
select ArticleId, sum(cost*quantity)/sum(quantity) as AverageCost, count(PurchaseId) 
where PurchaseId in (select top 2 * from PurchasesTable order by PurchaseDate)
from vsboremix.dbo.PurchaseTable join vsboremix.dbo.DocumentTable on pt.DocumentId=DocumentTable.DocumentId
Group by ArticleId    
// I omitted some joins so as to simplify the query 
// (I also need to bring in some tax/etc. values from separate tables)
```

I get a " Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." error, [FIXED] but I'm not sure if this query is even the right direction or there would be a simpler or better way to do this?

For the articleId's I find less than two purchases, I would need to run a separate query to get other information to adjust their average, so I'd also need this query to have every ArticleId whether there were any purchases on record or not.

I'd also need to evolve this query since there are 7 stores I'd need to run this for and their values would be different [store ID's also held in the same table that holds purchase dates], so I would have to run this query 7 times and the subquery another 7 times.

Any advice on fixing the error or restructuring the query would be appreciated!

--[EDIT]: I fixed the error but the query returns only seven values and all their counts are 1 (there should be 190 thousand per store) so the query's format or the subquery are wrong...

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server (based on the use of `top`), you can do this using window functions:

```
select ArticleId, sum(cost*quantity)/sum(quantity) as AverageCost, count(ArticleId) 
from (select pt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ArticleId order by PurchaseDate desc) as seqnum
      from PurchaseTable pt
     ) pt
where seqnum <= 2
Group by ArticleId;
```

Comment: This works, but it only returns those that have at least one purchase (not those that have zero). [If getting the others is too hard in this query I can just find the ArticleId's missing form this and run the other query for them, though...]

Comment: The divide by zero is because `sum(quantity)` is zero (presumably).  Your original question only mentions one table.  If data is not in that table, it will not be in the results.

Comment: You're right on both accounts. for those without any purchases there would be no records but I think this should be solved with a join so I'll look at that. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to verify the results of your query and they're wrong. Some of the ArticleId's it returns as having only one purchase have inf act over 20... Maybe this is because of the joins I omited (from vsboremix.dbo.PurchaseTable pt join vsboremix.dbo.DocumentTable on pt.DocumentId=DocumentTable.DocumentId)?

Comment: Not sure why, but using count(PurchaseId) was the cause of the errors and of the divide by zero problem. Using count(ArticleId) instead solved both, I edited your answer to reflect it and accepted it again